# Prefix (Figure or Table) in List of Figures and List of Tables in ConTeXt

Tags: table-of-contents, context

I am trying to display the prefix (i.e., Figure or Table) in List of Figures and List of Tables. I am using ConTeXt MkIV.

I used `\setuplist[figure][prefix=yes]` and `\setuplist[table][prefix=yes]`, to no avail. The lists were generated but they show the caption and table or figure number without the prefix Table or Figure. What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the `label` of float and not the `prefix`.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\setuplist[figure][label=figure,width=4em]

\starttext

\completelistoffigures

\placefigure{Dummy figure}{\externalfigure[dummy-1]}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Dummy me. I thought that was a prefix, Thanks a lot.